# SharePoint Search Service is not working

Tags: 2007, search

I am using SharePoint Server 2007 with collaboration portal template on Windows Server 2008. When I use the following function from Central Administration from Application Management -> search -> Manage Search Service, I met with the following error message, any ideas what is wrong?

The search service is currently offline. Visit the Services on Server page in SharePoint Central Administration to verify whether the service is enabled. This might also be because an indexer move is in progress.

Comment: Check here: Central Administration>Operation>Servers in Farm. It will list the services on that server (you can scroll through the other servers in the farm as well) and what their status is.

Comment: It lists a couple of items, which one(s) should I check?

Answer (score 3):

well the first thing i would do (before posting here) would be to visit the Services on Server page in SharePoint Central Administration to verify whether the service is enabled...

Comment: Actually, I do not know know where is "Services on Server page"? I did not find anything called Server page from Application Management Tab of Central Administration?

Comment: @George2: It's on the Operations menu. Top-left corner from memory.

Comment: On the top-left corner, there is Topology and Services category, and there are two items related, "Servers in farm" and "Services on server". Which one do you mean or you mean something else?

Comment: As it say in the error message: **Services on Server**. Check if Search service is running.

Comment: Actually just checked and both will show services running

Answer (score 1):

As Anders said, make sure the service is running.  Second, it is always a good idea to start by looking at the SharePoint ULS logs.  The number of potential issues are too numerous to list.

Here is a good primer I posted last year on Beginning SharePoint Troubleshooting.
http://nextconnect.blogspot.com/2009/05/beginning-sharepoint-troubleshooting.html

Comment: Actually, I do not know know where is "Services on Server page"? I did not find anything called Server page from Application Management Tab of Central Administration? And how to see ULS logs?

Comment: The details are covered in the blog post.

Comment: 1. I want to confirm with you that you mean Central Administration -> Operations -> Topology and Services category -> Servers in the Farm. Is it what you mean? 2. If yes, which one(s) should I check for my issue? I find a couple of services listed here.

Answer (score 0):

George -

- Go to Central Administration.
- Click 'Operations'
- Under Topology and Services click 'Services on Server'
- Select the 'Search Indexing' role to only show search related services.
- Use the Server drop down to check the services on each server in your farm
- If none of the servers says 'started' in green next to the relevant search service (maybe Office SharePoint Server Search) then the search service is not running in your farm and you need to activate it on one of the servers.